# How can we load third party module dynamically in angular 2

Tags: angular

How can we load third party module dynamically in angular 2. Using Angular CLI for production build (AOT). It uses webpack which generates all the build files for both early and lazy loaded after running build command ng build --prod.

I tried to load third party module using require js, webpack has created chunk js file for third party module just like lazy loaded module. I have then used JIT compiler to create component of third party module.  It works fine for me.

I am looking for solution where Third party module will provide me compiled component and I do not need to create component using Jit.  I am looking for solution where will just load third party module dynamically and it will start rendering their component in my angular 2 application.

Comment: Angular 2 is pretty old. You should upgrade to a newer version, for example 6.

Comment: That doesn't matter, the issue is apparently still not solved in newer versions of Angular 7 .... :(

Answer (score 0):

We are loading lazy loaded module using Require JS. Lazy loaded module(sample.module.js) is placed by end user(inside custom/sampleLib) . End user generates lazy loaded module from their application. Importing jit compiler to our system to create end user's component on demand.  Still could not find any solution other than JiT.

```
require.ensure(
      ["assets/samples/sample.module.js"], 
      (require) => {
        let SampleCo = require(assets/samples/sample.module.js");
        this._compiler
          .compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(
            SampleCo.SampleCustomModule
          ).then((compiled) => {
            const component1 = compiled.componentFactories.find(
              (m) => m.selector == "sample-comp1"
            );    });
          //here we create component with ViewContainerRefr
      },
      "custom/sampleLib" 
}
```